# Unity: How to move the camera by a specific amount in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm trying to take two seperate screenshots from my camera in Unity. I set my camera position in the script and then try to take a screenshot eacch time. But when I compare screenshots, I see that both of them are the same. I guess that the problem is with the targetTexture of my camera, but I don't know how to solve it.I have been trying to figure this out for a very long time and can't for some reason. Thanks!

```
public Camera myCamera;

Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(0, -0.1f, 0);
RenderTexture renderTexture1 = myCamera.targetTexture;

Texture2D renderResult1 = new Texture2D(renderTexture1.width, renderTexture1.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
Rect rect1 = new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture1.width, renderTexture1.height);
renderResult1.ReadPixels(rect1, 0, 0);

byte[] byteArray1 = renderResult1.EncodeToPNG();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("{0}/screenshots/screen{2}_{1}.png", Application.dataPath, Time.frameCount-1, 1), byteArray1);

RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTexture1);

Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0);
RenderTexture renderTexture2 = myCamera.targetTexture;

Texture2D renderResult2 = new Texture2D(renderTexture2.width, renderTexture2.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture2.width, renderTexture2.height);
renderResult2.ReadPixels(rect2, 0, 0);

byte[] byteArray2 = renderResult2.EncodeToPNG();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("{0}/screenshots/screen{2}_{1}.png", Application.dataPath, Time.frameCount-1, 2), byteArray2);

RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTexture2);
myCamera.targetTexture = null;
```

Comment: Isnt 0.1 and -0.1 to close to significantly see a difference? Do you see the expected difference in the editor or runtime? And I recommend you make a method for your screenshot rather than duplicating its easier to debug and read.